# grub will not boot ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader

this is my first attempt at Linux. I'm trying to dual boot XP sp2 and Ubuntu 11.10. I have the following partitions:
Primary 115GB windows     ntfs
Primary 1GB /boot               ext4
Primary 25 GB /                    ext4
Logical 125 GB /home         ext4
Swap

I put the boot loader in the /boot partition. Than I modified the boot.ini file and put a grldr and menu.lis file that I downloaded at http://www.icpug.org.uk/national/linnwin/step1-xp.htm

I than used an ISO CD to install Ubuntu 11.10. I had to check nomodeset for it to work but it install and I was able to use ubuntu. Once I restarted my PC I got the option to choose from windows XP or start Linux. Windows works fine but when I select start Linux it goes to a GRUB4DOS screen with the only option being "Default Boot on HD 0" which basically reboots my PC. If I press e to edit commands before booting I get "rootnoverify (hd0,0)", "chainloader +1" and a "boot" option . How do I get Ubuntu to boot?

Comment: Why don't you just install Ubuntu normally and let it set up grub for you?  Also there's no reason to have a /boot partition.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: @jrg Why not migrate it to linux? It looks like a linux question. I don't see anything wrong with this question I had a similar problem just now with my 12.10 not booting -I couldn't get out of grub and have no idea how to command grub to do amything useful

Comment: @Magpie it's too old to mirate, so it can't get moved to unix.se.